# How to create a channel in Odoo Discuss module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

My company recently install Odoo 9 (Community) and I have to face problems with the **module Discuss**.

When I want to create a new channel "#myCustomChannel" in the interface nothing happen...

Maybe I have to configure something in an other menu ? I saw in *"Configuration/Technical/Mail" => Channels and Channel/Partners...*

I tried in "Channels" to create a group and join it but nothing happen when I go back to "Inbox/Create Channel" and typing the group name that I have created...

Please can anyone help me ! 
Thanks in advance :) !

Laura.

Comment: hello @Laura_AAnds it's working, i think u have not latest source so download it

Comment: Hi @user00000341 ! Thanks for your reply ! My current version is 9.0-20151124, I'm in Linux server with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: welcome  now working or not ????

Comment: I'm doing right now the update :) I hope it will work ! I will keep you updated !

Comment: We install the odoo v9 with packaged installer, not git... How can I make the link with git to update odoo with latest version ? We don't want to loose  all our configurations with clone depository... Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Finally, we are doing the clone depository. I will keep you in touch !

Comment: u have any problem or not????

Comment: Okay, I have the latest version 9.0c-20151210 but problem persist....

Comment: When I test with Admin it works ! Other users can't... How can I give them the good rights to perform this action on module "Discuss" ?

Comment: EDIT for the previous comment : When my colleague test it in his local install with Admin rights it works ! Other users can't... And me with the same install in my localhost in Admin mode it doesn't works... I'm loosing my mind :/

Comment: put ur issue screnshot

Comment: We decided to remove the install and purchase the enterprise edition. Thanks again for your help ! We think that the problem is probably due to a corrupt install...

Answer (score 1):

Create new channel by below xml code.

```
<record model="mail.channel" id="channel_sb_1">
    <field name="name">Medical Refill</field>
    <field name="public">public</field>
    <field name="description">Medical refill information details.</field>
</record>
```

Than create new mail.message with this channel as referenced document.

```
channel_id = self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object('sb_medical_assistance_records.channel_sb_1')
channel_id.message_post(
                        subject='SnippetBucket Technologies',
                        body='''Hi... Tejaskumar Tank, SnippetBucket.com''',
                        subtype='mail.mt_comment')
```

Its create new channel and able to send new message in newly created channel.